# Matrix, Null space, Col space

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Regarding:

Prove or provide a counterexample: let $A \in \mathbb{M}_{n \times n}$. Then $\mathbb{R}^n=ColA + NullA$.

--

So I think this is false, because I can take a matrix:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 &0 \\ 
 0&  0& 0\\ 
 0& 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$

And we have $\dim ColA=1$, $\dim NullA=0$, and $\dim \mathbb{R}^3=3$,

and we know that $\mathbb{R}^n=ColA + NullA$ if and only if $\dim (ColA+NullA)= \dim \mathbb{R}^n$.

The only problem that I have here, is that I am not 100% sure that $\dim NullA=0$ and that $\dim ColA + \dim NullA = \dim (ColA+NullA)$

I would love to here some explanation regarding those kind of spaces :)

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Regarding $\dim Null A$, $A\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{bmatrix} = 0$ and $A\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\1\end{bmatrix} = 0$

Comment: No. Here $\dim({\rm Null}(A))=2$. The solution space is $\{(0,x_2,x_3)\mid x_2,x_3\in\mathbb{R}\}$.

Comment: @BernardPan Thank you, can you please explain me why is that? I think that I did not completely understand Null Space. :)

Comment: ${\rm Null(A)}=\{\vec{x}\mid A\vec{x}=\mathbf{0}\}$ is the set of all vector $\vec{x}$ such that $A\vec{x}=\mathbf{0}$. You just set the variables to be $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ and solve this linear system.

Comment: @BernardPan Thank you for that! So if we take Ben's example (down here), than $NullA=0$, because they are no free variables? Thanks!

Comment: @MathLover I wonder how you concluded that $\operatorname{Null} A$ contains just $\mathbf 0$, for both your example and the example from Ben Grossmann below? For both cases the null spaces contain more vectors, and their $\dim$ are positive. There could be confusion on the meaning of null space or how to solve $A\mathbf v = \mathbf 0$.

Comment: @peterwhy Well yeah, I am confused right now... If you have some time to explain that for me I will very appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that the statement is false, but the counterexample you give does not work. Instead, consider the matrix
$$
A = \pmatrix{0&1\\0&0}.
$$

Comment: Oh, so in my example, $NullA=2$, and here in yours $NullA=0$? Is that correct? If you have some time for a brief explanation - I will very appreciate that! :)

Comment: @MathLover If you solve this $A\mathbf v=\mathbf0$, you will find some non-zero $\mathbf v$, which means $Null A$ contains more than the zero vector and has positive $\dim$.

Comment: @peterwhy Did you say it about my example or Ben's one?

Comment: @MathLover It is true for my example as well. In particular, we have
$$
\operatorname{Col}(A) = \operatorname{Null}(A) = \operatorname{span}\{(1,0)^T\}.
$$

Comment: So I don't understand, In your case dimColA+dimNullA $= 2$, and also dim$\mathbb{R}^2=2$ ?

Comment: @MathLover It is true that 
$$
\dim \operatorname{Col}(A) + \dim \operatorname{Null}(A) = \dim \Bbb R^2,
$$
but it is not true that
$$
\operatorname{Col}(A) + \operatorname{Null}(A) = \Bbb R^2.
$$
Do you understand the difference?

Comment: No, because if Col(A) and Null(A) are subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^2$, and  dimColA+dimNullA $=$ dim$\mathbb{R}^2$, than Col(A)+Null(A)=$\mathbb{R}^2$. So maybe those are not subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: @MathLover What you have said is not true. If $U$ and $V$ are subspaces, then what is the definition of $U + V$?

Comment: $U+V$ is also a subspace, not?

Comment: @MathLover Yes, it is also a subspace, but be more specific. If $U = V = \operatorname{span}\{(1,0)^T\}$, then *which subspace* of $\Bbb R^2$ is $U + V$?

Comment: $span${${(1,0)^T}$}

Comment: @MathLover Exactly. So indeed, $\operatorname{Col}(A) + \operatorname{Null}(A) \neq  \Bbb R^2$

Comment: Oh alright! So because span{$(0,1)^T$} is not spanning $\mathbb{R}^2$, than  Col(A)+Null(A)$\ne \mathbb{R}^2$. I understand why Col(A)=span{$(0,1)^T$}, buy why do Null(A) also?

Comment: @MathLover The nullspace of $A$ is the solution space to $Ax = 0$. In this case, 
$$
Ax = 0 \implies \pmatrix{0&1\\0&0} \pmatrix{x_1\\x_2} = 0 \implies \begin{cases} 
x_2 = 0,\\ 0 = 0.
\end{cases}
$$
We see that $x$ is in the nullspace if and only if $x_2 = 0$, which is to say that $x$ is a multiple of the vector $(1,0)^T$.

Comment: Thank you so much @BenGrossmann !!